# How can i convert my curl cURL Request to node js?

Tags: node.js, curl, node-libcurl

I have to create an api in node js i am creating it into curl how can i convert the cURL Request into node js. how can i pass url,header and data binary in node js? The follwing is the cURL Request?

```
curl -v "https://us-extract.api.smartystreets.com/?auth-id=AUTH_ID&auth-token=AUTH_TOKEN" -H "content-type: application/json" --data-binary ""
```

Comment: you can use node-fetch or request or axios or built-in 'https' modules

Comment: do you want to use node-libcurl specifically?

Comment: use node request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some very handy tools for this, check out https://curl.trillworks.com/#node, it will convert curl requests to code in Node.js, Python, Go etc.

I've changed your curl request slightly to:

```
curl -v -X POST "https://us-extract.api.smartystreets.com/?auth-id=AUTH_ID&auth-token=AUTH_TOKEN" -H "content-type: application/json" --data-binary "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway,Mountain View, CA 94043"
```

(Note I've redacted your auth-id and auth-token, we don't other people to use these.. :-))

In your example the output will be like as below, note this uses the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library. You'll have to do an npm install request to add this to your project.

```
var request = require('request');

// Put your auth id and token here.
const AUTH_ID = "";
const AUTH_TOKEN = "";

var headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
};

var dataString = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway,Mountain View, CA 94043';

var options = {
    url: 'https://us-extract.api.smartystreets.com/?auth-id=' + AUTH_ID + '&auth-token=' + AUTH_TOKEN,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString,
    json: true // Set this to parse the response to an object.
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
        // Log the API output.
        (body.addresses || []).forEach((element, index) => {
            console.log(`api_output (address #${index+1}):`, element.api_output);
        });
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Comment: Thank yo so much. problem solved to using this code

Comment: i have a small doubt  how can i get api_output  details in json body                                iam using         console.log(body.api_output); but the result is undefined

Comment: Oh yes, I'll update the answer. If we add an option of json: true to the options object, we'll get back the response as an object rather than as a string.

Comment: I've updated the answer, each address has an api_output array that we can access as above. I believe this is what you need!

Comment: How to write a tsv file in Node? i have to write a column in node using tsv file.pls help me ?

Comment: Could you add this in another question? I think that would be better :-). I'm sure we can find a solution to your problem!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58371964/how-can-write-a-column-in-tsv-file-using-node-js                                                                 pls answer me?